# VSCode is not able to connect to Xdebug

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, xdebug, xdebug-3

I tried to setup the Xdebug step debugger in my docker container to be able to connect to my Docker container.

This is my configuration snippet from the `launch.json` in the `.vscode` directory in my project:

```json
{
    "name": "Xdebug",
    "type": "php",
    "request": "launch",
    "hostname": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 9000,
    "pathMappings": {
        "/var/www/html/": "${workspaceFolder}/code/",
    },
},
```

This is the Code Snippet of my `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
services: 
  webserver:
    container_name: webserver_orderlinev3
    build: webserver
    ports: 
      - 8080:80
      - 9000:9000
    volumes: 
      - ./code:/var/www/html
      - ./webserver/php-ini-overrides.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-ini-overrides.ini
      - ./webserver/phpsessions:/var/www/phpsessionfiles
      - ./xdebuglog:/tmp/xdbglog

    extra_hosts:
      - host.docker.internal:host-gateway
    environment:
      - XDEBUG_MODE=debug,develop,coverage,profile,trace
```

And those where my php.ini overrides

```ini
[session]
session.save_handler=files
session.save_path="/var/www/phpsessionfiles"

[xdebug]
xdebug.client_port=9000
xdebug.mode=off

xdebug.discover_client_host=on
xdebug.client_host = host.docker.internal

xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp

xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.log=/tmp/xdbglog/xdebug_remote.log
```

As this is the log output from the xdebug.log

```
[17] Log opened at 2022-10-25 16:22:46.248594
[17] [Step Debug] INFO: Checking remote connect back address.
[17] [Step Debug] INFO: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
[17] [Step Debug] INFO: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
[17] [Step Debug] INFO: Client host discovered through HTTP header, connecting to 172.29.0.1:9000.
[17] [Step Debug] WARN: Creating socket for '172.29.0.1:9000', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
[17] [Step Debug] WARN: Could not connect to client host discovered through HTTP headers, connecting to configured address/port: host.docker.internal:9000. :-|
[17] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: 172.29.0.1:9000 (from REMOTE_ADDR HTTP header), host.docker.internal:9000 (fallback through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port). :-)
[17] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/html/orderline/api/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="8.0.24" protocol_version="1.0" appid="17"><engine version="3.1.5"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2022 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[17] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 1 -n max_children -v 100
[17] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="max_children" success="1"></response>

[17] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 2 -n max_data -v 8192
[17] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="max_data" success="1"></response>

[17] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 3 -t exception -x "Notice"
[17] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="3" id="170008"></response>

[17] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 4 -t exception -x "Warning"
[17] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="4" id="170009"></response>

[17] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 5 -t exception -x "Error"
[17] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="5" id="170010"></response>

[17] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 6 -t exception -x "Exception"
[17] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="6" id="170011"></response>

[17] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 7 -t exception -x "Fatal error"
[17] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="7" id="170012"></response>

[17] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 8 -t exception -x "Parse error"
[17] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="8" id="170013"></response>

[17] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 9 -t exception -x "Unknown error"
[17] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="9" id="170014"></response>

[17] [Step Debug] <- run -i 10
[17] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="10" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[17] Log closed at 2022-10-25 16:22:46.308352
```

I do not get any clue out of this, why it is actually not working.

The Host port to Guest port Redirection seems to be working since I can connect to the webserver through `localhost:8080`
I watched now several YouTube tutorials to this topic but I have no clue what I'm doing wrong.

Xdebug seems to connect to `docker.host.internal` but the gateway seems to be blocking this - although I turned off my firewall even for testing (again turned it on).

May someone with experience in docker and Xdebug may help me? I would really appreciate.

P.S. I'm not using any VPN connection - its disabled for exactly that reason.

Comment: 1) *"VSCode is not able to connect to Xdebug"* It's Xdebug that connects to debug client (VSCode in your case) and NOT other way around. 2) `ports:       - 8080:80      - 9000:9000` -- what `9000:9000` is for? if that is for Xdebug then it's obviously wrong (see #1). If it's for php-fpm then _might_ be needed (not sure, but quite unlikely).

Comment: 3) *"Xdebug seems to connect to docker.host.internal "*  It's `host.docker.internal` and not `docker.host.internal`.  4) *"but the gateway seems to be blocking this"* Yes, because of #2 -- Docker listens on TCP 9000 and VSCode is unable to. BTW -- I suggest you stick to the default `9003` port for Xdebug v3 -- it was changed for a reason, to avoid confusions and clashing with php-fpm (that also uses 9000 port by default)

Comment: 5) *" INFO: Connected to debugging client: 172.29.0.1:9000"* it is actually connected to (VSCode?) anyway -- as it sets breakpoints for Exceptions.

Comment: 6) *"xdebug.remote_connect_back=0 xdebug.remote_enable=on xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp"* This is Xdebug v2, they do nothing in Xdebug v3. The last line does not do anything in v2 either (as it;s the only handler possible anyway).

Comment: 7) *"xdebug.mode=off"* You must be enabling Xdebug somewhere else, right? Because this tells Xdebug to not to do anything.

Comment: 8) I suggest you check your actual/live Xdebug settings via `xdebug_info()` captured in the same way you are trying to debug (CLI or web page -- as they may have different configs). So you can see and confirm that the actual settings are exactly set as expected. Also check https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IN6ihpJSFDw

Comment: removed the settings 
```xdebug.remote_connect_back=0``` 
```xdebug.remote_enable=on``` 
```xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp````

it already meant 
```host.docker.internal```

setup dockerfile
```9003:9003```
setup
launch.json
```
        {
            "name": "Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "hostname": "127.0.0.1",
            "port": 9003,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html/orderline/api": "${workspaceFolder}/php/",
            },
        },
```
now same xdebug-log
 same falis but on port 9003

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/cSgfHat

Comment: [23] [Step Debug] WARN: Creating socket for '172.24.0.1:9003', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
[

Comment: [23] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: 172.24.0.1:9003 (from REMOTE_ADDR HTTP header), host.docker.internal:9003 (fallback through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).

Comment: so now xdbg seems to connect successfully but the step debugger in vsc does not show anything -.-

Comment: *"setup dockerfile 9003:9003"* WHY? See my #1 and #2. If Docker is listening on Xdebug port then VSCode may not be able to listen there. It's Xdebug that connects to client (so it's an OUTGOING connection from inside the container to the host system) and NOT other way around.

Comment: *"so now xdbg seems to connect successfully but the step debugger in vsc does not show anything "* I see no LINE BREAKPOINTS in your original Xdebug log. Only standard "stop on Exception" ones....

Comment: thank you, its up and running now - only moving backwards is not fully functional as it breaks the script - but anyways thank you so much <3

Answer (score 1):

thank you, its up and running now finally
Without @LazyOne i would have been stuck here for some more time, special thanks to him <3

this is the config

```ini
[session]
session.save_handler=files
session.save_path="/var/www/phpsessionfiles"

[xdebug]
#xdebug.client_port=9003
#xdebug.mode=off

#xdebug.discover_client_host=on
xdebug.client_host = host.docker.internal

xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.log=/tmp/xdbglog/xdebug_remote.log
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3.2"
 

 
services: 
  webserver:
    container_name: webserver_orderlinev3
    build: webserver
    ports: 
      - 8080:80

    volumes: 
    #setup virtual webroot
      - ./code:/var/www/html/
    # setup react
      - ./react_build:/var/www/html/orderline/
    #setup virtual webroot
      - ./code/orderline/api:/var/www/html/orderline/api

    #php.ini overrides
      - ./webserver/php-ini-overrides.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-ini-overrides.ini
    #php sessions
      - ./webserver/phpsessions:/var/www/phpsessionfiles
    #xdebug
      - ./xdebuglog:/tmp/xdbglog

    extra_hosts:
      - host.docker.internal:host-gateway
    environment:
      - XDEBUG_MODE=debug,develop,coverage,profile,trace
```

```json
{
    // Verwendet IntelliSense zum Ermitteln möglicher Attribute.
    // Zeigen Sie auf vorhandene Attribute, um die zugehörigen Beschreibungen anzuzeigen.
    // Weitere Informationen finden Sie unter https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "hostname": "127.0.0.1",
            "port": 9003,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html": "${workspaceFolder}/code",
            },
        },
    ]
}
```